# ProxyError while installing Python packages. (With both Conda and Pip)

Tags: proxy, pip, conda, http-proxy

I am trying to get the Pip and Conda to work inside the proxy Work environment. I was able to get it to work in the past from work but somehow it doesn't work anymore in the work from home setting using Citrix Gateway. Here is all i have tried. Could you please advice what i am missing?

1. I added the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY environment variables with the below format under system variables

> `set http_proxy=http://userid:password@address:port`
> `set https_proxy=https://userid:password@address:port`

I got the address and port using the following command. I could not find a port 8080 in the list. so i picked a latest one with port 443.

> `netstat -an | findstr EST`

2. I also made sure the `Path` Variable under system variable contains the path to the `python` and `pip` executables.
3. In addition to this, i also tried setting the `ssl_verify=false` in the `.condarc` file under user directory. I also tried adding http & https proxy in that file as suggested in the anaconda docs. However none of this worked.
4. I am able to access the commands `pip list` and `conda info --all` without any issues.

Could you please advice. thank you!

Comment: Your companies IT department might be better abel to assist you here. Probably your proxy settings are not correct

Answer (score 0):

What's your pip version?

There are some issues with pip version 20.3.x.
please refer to this issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9190